# What happen when using as admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In Rails 3 in action its based on 3.1 so its kind old because i am using 3.2.12 when i tried to assign admin without make it free for mass assign it raises an error and thats because the differences between 3.1 and 3.2 as the author said.
so its better to use which on of the following and what is the difference ?

first method in controller

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user], :as => :admin)
    if @user.save
        flash[:notice] = "User has been created."
        redirect_to admin_users_path
    else
        flash[:alert] = "User has not been created."
        render :action => "new"
    end
  end
```

and in model

```
 attr_accessible :email, :password, :admin, :as => :admin
```

second method in controller

```
   def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user], :without_protection => true)
    @user.admin = params[:user][:admin] == "1"
    if @user.save
        flash[:notice] = "User has been created."
        redirect_to admin_users_path
    else
        flash[:alert] = "User has not been created."
        render :action => "new"
    end
  end
```

without adding the line above in the model

which one will protect from mass-assign or both are free ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `attr_accessible` and `:without_protection => true` can be used to allow mass assignment on attributes of a model they are defined in.

> so its better to use which on of the following and what is the difference ?

To answer this concern, I think using `attr_accessible` is better because you define exactly which attributes you want to allow for mass assignment compared to `:without_protection => true` which opens up **all attributes** in your model to be mass assigned.

Usually, passing the `:without_protection => true` is okay if you know exactly what the user input is, for e.g. when seeding data.  But for inputs that come from a form (user input) you want to specify exactly what is allowed for mass assignment.

Hope this helps.

**Update:**

In the following statement, the `as` option you supply to `attr_accessible` confirms that the attributes `email, password and admin` are allowed only if the user is `admin`.

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :admin, :as => :admin
```

Comment: i want use it to allow creating admins, is that okay ? and also could you explain what is :as :admin ? because i do not know it..

Comment: @Dexter, I'm a little unclear when you say "I want to use it to allow creating admins", how are you creating admins?

Comment: by check box in the add users form , but only admin can create users as admin

Comment: @Dexter, please see the update I added.  And the answer to your comment is yes, you can go ahead and use that statement to only allow admins to allow mass assignment on those attributes.

Comment: and what this line means ? `@user = User.new(params[:user], :as => :admin)`

Comment: @Dexter, that statement will allow the attributes allowed via `attr_accessible ..., :as => :admin` for any user "basically".  It's better not to use this kind of statement as it overrides the purpose.

Comment: i added `attr_accessible....` to my model then added `@user = User.new(params[:user], :as => :admin)` then my test is passing , but if i used this `@user = User.new(params[:user])` it raises mass-assign again so i should use both

Comment: "it overrides the purpose" what do you mean by this ?

Comment: I think you should create two tests, one for regular user and another for admin user and test both cases.

Comment: What I meant by "it overrides the purpose" is that if you are forcing creating new `User` as admin from your controller then defining `attr_accessible..., :as => :admin` does not really add any value since everything is coming in for `admin`.

Comment: could you check this question please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560723/def-to-s-not-working-in-model